# Swollen lump on dogs belly

Tags: dogs, skin-condition

I have a male golden retriever and he's just over a year old. I noticed this lump on his belly near his penis. He doesn't appear to be in pain and it didn't bother him when I was inspecting it. I've never noticed him biting it or anything but he often licks down there so it's not something I'd see as unusual if he was.
[image: spot in belly]

He sleeps indoors and he is on a lead most if the time when we go for walks. I could probably pop this with a pin but I'd like to know what it is before I do anything.

It doesn't look sore and it's very soft almost like it's filled with fluid. He has had similar, but much smaller lumps in the past and that he usually pops and a yellow liquid comes out. The vet said they are just from nettles. This one is big and he has yet to pop this one which has me more curious.

Comment: Take your dog to a vet. It could be a tumour. Even if it's benign, it needs the attention of a qualified vet.

Comment: If it is soft with liquid I would drain it.  Vet is the safe bet.

Comment: It looks like an umbilical hernia. Do **not** attempt to drain it.

Comment: Did you ever find out what that was on your dog? My dog just had the same identical thing show up on him, just looking for answers

Comment: Yes, we asked the vet last time he had a checkup and the vet said it's his belly button. It's a minor umbilical hernia but it's not worth doing surgery on. The vet didn't seem to concerned it would cause the dog any health problems.  it shouldn't cause any problems but if it starts to grow it needs to be addressed right away.

Comment: @DanHastings would you post what the vet told you as an answer to your question?  Answering your own question is encouraged and will help others in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We asked the vet last time he had a checkup and the vet said it's his belly button. It's a minor umbilical hernia but it's not worth doing surgery on. The vet didn't seem too concerned it would cause the dog any health problems.  it shouldn't cause any problems but if it starts to grow it needs to be addressed right away.

**Update** :
My dog was always biting at this and he eventually popped it himself. Didn't cause much trouble. It was fairly well healed by the time I spotted that it had burst and it seems fine now.